# How can I display a two column array in PHP/HTML?

Tags: php, html, arrays, magento

I have an array of icons. Right now, we only display them in buckets of 4. So if you have 7 icons, the 4th icon on the first slide will repeat as the 8th on the second slide. That's because the 3rd index of the array is stored in that same spot. To fix this, I want to loop through the array instead of explicitly iterating icon by icon.

```
            <?php if (!empty($icons)) { // if we have icons attributes 
              // NOTE: we've changed it to show as many sets as we can
              //       (sets of 4)
                $number_of_sets = ceil(count($icons) / 4);
            $k=0; // for inner iteration
            for ($j=0;$j < $number_of_sets; $j++) {
                $slide_total ++;
                ?>

                <div class="cf slide icon-slide">
                    <?php
            // up to 4 icons
                    if (is_array($icons) && !empty($icons[$k])) {
                        $icon1 = $icons[$k];
                        $k++;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="col left">
                        <div class="cf icon">
                            <div class="col thumb">
                                <img src="<?=$icon1['thumb']?>" alt="<?=htmlentities($icon1['post_title'])?>" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="colR details">
                                <h4><?=$icon1['post_title']?></h4>
                                <p><?=$icon1['post_content']?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
            // up to 4 icons
                        if (is_array($icons) && !empty($icons[$k])) {
                            $icon2 = $icons[$k];
                            $k++;
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div class="cf icon">
                            <div class="col thumb">
                                <img src="<?=$icon2['thumb']?>" alt="<?=htmlentities($icon2['post_title'])?>" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="colR details">
                                <h4><?=$icon2['post_title']?></h4>
                                <p><?=$icon2['post_content']?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php
            // up to 4 icons
                    if (is_array($icons) && !empty($icons[$k])) {
                        $icon3 = $icons[$k];
                        $k++;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="colR right">
                        <div class="cf icon">
                            <div class="col thumb">
                                <img src="<?=$icon3['thumb']?>" alt="<?=htmlentities($icon3['post_title'])?>" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="colR details">
                                <h4><?=$icon3['post_title']?></h4>
                                <p><?=$icon3['post_content']?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php
            // up to 4 icons
                        if (is_array($icons) && !empty($icons[$k])) {
                            $icon4 = $icons[$k];
                            $k++;
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div class="cf icon">
                            <div class="col thumb">
                                <img src="<?=$icon4['thumb']?>" alt="<?=htmlentities($icon4['post_title'])?>" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="colR details">
                                <h4><?=$icon4['post_title']?></h4>
                                <p><?=$icon4['post_content']?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- // end icon slide -->
                <?php
            } // end for $j (number of sets of 4 icons
            ?>
```

My proposed solution:

```
            <?php if (!empty($icons)) { 
                $num_cols = 2;
                $i = 0;
                $slide_items = 4;
                ?>

                <div class="cf slide icon-slide">
                    <?php foreach ( $icons as $icon ) {


                        echo $i++%$num_cols==0 ? '</div><div class="col" style="width: 250px;">' : '';

                        ?>
                        <div class="cf icon">
                            <div class="col thumb">
                                <img src="<?=$icon['thumb']?>" alt="<?=htmlentities($icon['post_title'])?>" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="colR details">
                                <h4><?=$icon['post_title']?></h4>
                                <p><?=$icon['post_content']?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                        <?php  } } // end if we have icons attributes ?>
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make another slide after I hit 4 icons. Adding the following line before the end of the foreach loop hasn't worked.

```
echo $i++%$slide_items==0 ? '</div><div class="cf slide icon-slide">' : '';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some logic for the loop:

```
$i = count( $icons );    

if ( $i % 4 != 0 )
    $i = $i + ( $i % 4 );

for( $n = 0; $n < $i; $n++ )
{

    if ( $n % 4 == 0 )
    {
        // code to open a row here
    }

    // code to open a column here

    // echo your icon here, use isset() or !empty().

    // code to close a column here

    if ( $n > 0 && $n % 3 == 0 )
    {
        // code to close a row here
    }

}
```

The IFs at the top is for keeping the column number consistent. Otherwise there'll be some weirdness at the end of the loop.

Comment: In the second if's condition, you might want to add `|| $n == $i - 1` so it closes the final row.

Comment: The column number will always 4 because of the IFs at the top, so we can be sure the final row will be closed. It's especially needed for tables, different column number might render badly on some browsers.

Comment: Right I missed that top part.